# Uncaught Exception with async constructor pattern

Tags: typescript, exception, promise

This class is somewhat special as it uses lots of async calls insdie the constructor, and constructors cannot be async, so I used a special pattern that I read about in the internet:

```
export class MapLayer {
    public Ready: Promise<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.instantiate();
    }

    async instantiate(): Promise<void> {
        return this.Ready = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.parseServiceDefiniton().then(() => {
               // ...
               resolve(undefined);
            }).catch((ex) => {
                console.log('reject');
                reject();
            });
        });
    }

    async parseServiceDefiniton(): Promise<boolean> {
        throw Error('test');
    }

}
```

And how I use it:

```
const lyr: MapLayer =  new MapLayer ();
    
     lyr.Ready.then(() => {
              
    
    }).catch(ex => {
       console.log(ex);
    });
```

Since exceptions can occur in the `parseServiceDefiniton` function, I'm simulating this case. And currently, I'm getting the following error:

> Uncaught (in promise): [object Undefined]

In the console I see:

> reject
>
> undefined

I do not see where I am not catching an exception!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is you use `async` inside `instantiate`. The machinery that makes `async` possible  will create another `Promise` that will wrap the `Promise` you return and this promise will actually not have it's exception caught (since you don't catch the error in the constructor)

The simplest solution is to remove `async`. Since you don't use `await` inside the body `async` is actually not needed:

```
export class MapLayer {
    public Ready!: Promise<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.instantiate();
    }

    instantiate(): Promise<void> {
        return this.Ready = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            this.parseServiceDefiniton().then(() => {
                // ...
                resolve(undefined);
            }).catch((ex) => {
                console.log('reject');
                reject(ex);
            });
        });
    }

    async parseServiceDefiniton(): Promise<boolean> {
        throw Error('test');
    }

}

const lyr: MapLayer = new MapLayer();

lyr.Ready.then(() => {
}).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex);
});
```

Or a version that uses async and does not use the `Promise` constructor needlessly:

```
export class MapLayer {
    public Ready!: Promise<any>;

    constructor() {
        this.Ready = this.instantiate();
    }

    async instantiate(): Promise<void> {
        try {
            await this.parseServiceDefiniton()
        } catch (ex) {
            console.log('reject');
            throw ex;
        }
    }

    async parseServiceDefiniton(): Promise<boolean> {
        throw Error('test');
    }

}

const lyr: MapLayer = new MapLayer();

lyr.Ready.then(() => {
}).catch(ex => {
    console.log(ex);
});
```